# help with SLAM, robotic platform and orientation

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new in this and I have to choose a robotic platform. I'm gonna work in a robotic platform with a kinect (from the xbox 360) using ROS packages to do SLAM (simultaneous localization and mapping). More than anything I need orientation about how to proceed in this subject. My goal is through a 2WD mobile robot do SLAM in a room for instance. I know that are some useful packages in ROS like gmapping and rviz, but I'm lost in the procedure.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258741/help-with-slam,-robotic-platform-and-orientation/) by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about starting with a [Turtlebot](http://www.turtlebot.com/)?

You can even [simulate it in Gazebo](Gazebo Bringup Guide) and follow the [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thanks man. By now I'm quite advanced with my project. So it'd be solved :)

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-08-28**:
Happy to hear that, if you think this answer solved your question, please mark it as "Correct" by clicking the round button with a check mark located on the left side of the answer

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-29**:
Done man :)